# Task.Factory.StartNew indentation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting

When I'm writing task creation code by hand, IDE formats this as follows:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //
    });
```

But when I Copy-Paste the same code, it becomes:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //
});
```

Sorry for niggling. But what's the standard or at least recommended formatting?

**UPD**

I'm using clean Visual Studio 2012, with auto-formatting on paste (`Tools`>`Options`>`Text Editor`>`C#`>`Formatting` - all checked).

Also I use `Ctrl+E,D` for document formatting. Nothing changes, both variants stay as they are

Comment: Copy/pasting usually doesn't trigger the IDE to auto-correct. Delete the final semi-colon and re-type it, it'll probably reformat. I think Ctrl+K+D also reformats the current page.

Comment: Also, are you using ReSharper ?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth In my experiance, IDE always formats on pasting code, by default. Also I use Ctrl+E+D, not K+D, did you mean that?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov No, only clean IDE. By the way, I've got the same formatting trouble in VS2012, 2010 and (not sure) 2008